# Id column in Strapi models

Tags: javascript, strapi

A quick question about the id column in models.
We're using Strapi in our project and PostgreSQL as our DBM.

The question is, I'm trying to make models in Strapi and I'm confused about ID column. Strapi has an ID column by self. Should I create an ID column in each model? Or I've to create an `_id` column by myself? Cause I've to make the relations between models and I need to know how to make an id column as a foreign key?

For example, I need to make a model like this:

```
id: integer - primary and foreign key 
name: varchar
parent_id: integer
description: text
```

In this model, I need to make a relation between id and parent_id. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i thinks as of now foreign key doesn't support in strapi